Django-translations not returning models translations on DRF
I have a project setup with django 3.2.5 and drf 3.14.0 on python 3.6 and postgres 9.6.
I followed the following steps to create a translatable model for learning products model.
using this library for translations here.
from translations.models import Translatable
class LearningProduct(Translatable):
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        _("Description"),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        _("Image"),
        upload_to="uploads/images/learning_products/%Y/%m/%d",
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    link = models.URLField(
        _("Link"),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "learning_product"
        verbose_name = _("Learning Product")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Learning Products")

    class TranslatableMeta:
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'link']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

added it to the admin panel as follows:
from translations.admin import TranslatableAdmin, TranslationInline

class LearningProductAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    inlines = [TranslationInline]

admin.site.register(LearningProduct, LearningProductAdmin)

it lets me save the model's translations for the specified fields. i have two languages setup in my settings as:
## Translation settings.
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ne', _('Nepali')),
)

i have my apiview setup as follows and it lets me fetch the model when no accept-language is passed as well as when En is passed as the accept-language but i run into the error given below it when i try get method woth accept-language as Ne.
views.py
# views.py
from rest_framework import generics
from core.models import LearningProduct

class LearningProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Learning Product data types.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = LearningProduct
        fields = '__all__'

class LearningProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = LearningProduct.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LearningProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(LearningProductListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.translate_related(
            'title',
            'description',
            'link',
        ).translate()

the error:
[log].ERROR Internal Server Error: /api/v2/learningproducts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 40, in list
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 171, in paginate_queryset
    return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\pagination.py", line 216, in paginate_queryset
    return list(self.page)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 883, in __iter__
    v = self[i]
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 188, in __getitem__
    self.object_list = list(self.object_list)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\querysets.py", line 54, in _fetch_all
    with Context(self._result_cache, *self._trans_rels) \
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\context.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.mapping, self.query = _get_purview(entity, hierarchy)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 199, in _get_purview
    _fill_entity(entity, hierarchy)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 195, in _fill_entity
    _fill_obj(obj)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 190, in _fill_obj
    included=detail['included'],
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 148, in _fill_entity
    iterable, model = _get_entity_details(entity)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 132, in _get_entity_details
    raise TypeError(error_message)
TypeError: `abc` is neither a model instance nor an iterable of model instances.
[log].ERROR Internal Server Error: /api/v2/learningproducts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 40, in list
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 171, in paginate_queryset
    return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\pagination.py", line 216, in paginate_queryset
    return list(self.page)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 883, in __iter__
    v = self[i]
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 188, in __getitem__
    self.object_list = list(self.object_list)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\querysets.py", line 54, in _fetch_all
    with Context(self._result_cache, *self._trans_rels) \
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\context.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.mapping, self.query = _get_purview(entity, hierarchy)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 199, in _get_purview
    _fill_entity(entity, hierarchy)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 195, in _fill_entity
    _fill_obj(obj)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 190, in _fill_obj
    included=detail['included'],
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 148, in _fill_entity
    iterable, model = _get_entity_details(entity)
  File "C:\my-site\env\lib\site-packages\translations\utils.py", line 132, in _get_entity_details
    raise TypeError(error_message)
TypeError: `abc` is neither a model instance nor an iterable of model instances.
[basehttp].ERROR "GET /api/v2/learningproducts/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165340

TypeError: abc is neither a model instance nor an iterable of model instances.
